# Render json with status update 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I'm trying to add a `before_action` that checks for a user and returns json to the angular app with a status of 401 if there is no user.

the function is simply

```
 def authenticate_user
   if !logged_in
     render json: {:status => 401}
   end
 end
```

However, this never hits my `httpInterceptor` and renders the json straight to the page. How can I get this response to return with the proper headers so the interceptor can handle a 401?

```
app.run(function($http, $cookies, $rootScope, $location) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
});

app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$cookies', '$location', '$window',
  function($cookies, $location, $window) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        return config
      },
      'response': function(response) {
        if ($location.$$path !== '/' && !$cookies.csrftoken){
          $location.path('/');
        }
        return response
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your interceptor to the httpProvider ?

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
})
```

See there : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: How do you request the API which should respond with a 401 ? With $http ?